# Attempting to move folder from C drive to folder in WSL/Ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, mv

I am making a website for my online book/media business, and I have some photos on my C drive (cover photos) that I would like to copy into my project directory in VSCode via WSL.

The file is stored in `/mnt/c/Users/etc/Downloads`. As I would still need to have this folder in `C`, I probably would just need to copy the contents of the folder and move it to an already made directory in my WSL project.

I have tried to make a directory in my WSL project via WSL with `mkdir` and then copy the contents of the file when I am on the path `/mnt/c` via `cp`. I have tried to move it into the folder in WSL with `mv` but it has not worked.

I have been at this for over a week now with no success. I have tried to find YouTube videos on it, and I have tried to get books on git from the library.  Either the really good books are checked out, or the books I have do not address this issue.

So, for example, I would make a directory in my current VSC project via WSL with `mkdir bookphotos`. Then I would use the terminal to go to the `mnt/c/Users/` path until I found my folder with my cover photos. I would then try to copy that folder with `cp` and move it to the WSL directory. It has not worked. Some help would be appreciated.

The full path to the folder is `/mnt/c/Users/warriors/bookphotos` when I am in the Ubuntu/WSL terminal. The project in VSC that I would like to move the folder into is `/home/sixwarriors/booksbusiness` - that is the directory where I have my html/css/javascript code. I would like to copy the `bookphotos` folder and move it into the `booksbusiness` directory so that I can use the stock photos on there.

Comment: What are the full path of the source and destination folders as seen from WSL? Add this information in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I updated the question with the paths.

Comment: Do you mean the source is: `/mnt/c/Users/warriors/bookphotos`? Note file and folder names are case sensitive in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can't you also add the error messages you are getting into your question? Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! So, I tried a few things.  @user68186 Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am not getting an error message. I went to the /mnt/c/Users/warriors path and tried to move the folder by mv to the directory in WSL and no error message occurs. It seems like it would work but when I check the directory in WSL it is not there. I then tried to extract the files in the photo directory to the directory in WSL but it is not recognizing it. I am a little lost.

Comment: Please be specific.  Edit your question with the exact commands you are using and copy/paste the output. We can't explain an error if you don't tell us what the error is! I would not suggest using `mv` because it will delete the origin files. Are you aware you need to use a `-r` recursive flag when copying more than one file (like a folder)?

Comment: @Nmath hey thanks for the advice! No, I didn't know about recursive. I have to study git a lot more. The books that I have on the subject are very simplistic and only handle basic commands. I will definitely study this! Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: So to copy a folder the syntax needs to be `cp -r /path/to/source /path/to/destination`. If you're copying to a path that needs elevated write permissions, you need to start the command with `sudo`

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem as solved and help others find the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To copy, try:

In WSL try the command:

```
cp -r /mnt/c/Users/warriors/bookphotos/ /home/sixwarriors/booksbusiness/
```

## To move, try:

```
mv /mnt/c/Users/warriors/bookphotos/ /home/sixwarriors/booksbusiness/
```

In both cases you should have `bookphotos` folder inside the `bookbusiness` folder with all it's contents.

## Try it from the Windows side

In the Ubuntu/WSL terminal enter:

```
cd ~/bookbusiness
explorer.exe .
```

This will open the `bookbusiness` folder File explorer. Now you can drag and drop the `bookphotos` folder inside the `bookbusiness` folder.

### Alternately...

Open File Explorer in Windows the usual way:

[image]

Then at the top type:

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\sixwarriors\booksbusiness
```

This will also open the `bookbusiness` folder File explorer. Now you can drag and drop the `bookphotos` folder inside the `bookbusiness` folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried tried the explorer method before but I kept trying to extract the files into the book directory in WSL but obviously it wasn't going to find that path. I didn't know that I could just drag the folder but I actually just did it. Thank you! And thanks for the command showing me how to move the directory. For some reason, I wasn't putting the entire path. I thought if I jut put the name of the directory it would move it there. That is where I went wrong. I need to study Git a lot more. Thank you for your time; you are appreciated!

Comment: @jumpman23 Just a heads-up that none of this has anything to do with Git. :-).  What will help is learning the shell, specifically the Bash shell (not to be confused with "Git Bash", a separate Windows program).  There are a lot of resources out there.  You might start with [this Microsoft (believe it or not) tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/shell/).  Best of luck!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds hmm that's interesting. I have been learning Git and using that inside the shell; I thought the git commands would be the same as those that would be used in the bash shell. I have always just looked at git and used those commands to work inside the shell. Well, maybe because I am using git to help develop my webpage and other computer programs. That is why I thought that. But as you stated I am sure that learning the shell would help a lot. And if I ever chose not to use git I would still know how to operate the Bash shell. Thanks for the help! I am studying the link.